# Avoid data mismatch between imported and manual data in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I have found a bunch of similar questions on this page, but nobody seems to have a workaround:

In my active sheet, columns A-H contain filtered, imported data from another sheet.
Columns I-U contain manual data.
I use column I as a helper column to be able to match the rows with imported column A, in case my source sheet gets updated with new rows.

whenever the source sheet is updated, it causes the filtered imported data in columns A-H to change, thus leading my manual data to mismatch.

I have come up with the idea of using an installable onEdit trigger that detects whenever updates to the source sheet cause the filtered imported data to change.

When certain criteria is true (aligned with the filter), it should create an index of all manual data in columsn I-U, and thanks to the matching helper column, re-place them to the new, correct row.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Define the active spreadsheet
  var activeSpreadsheet = e.source;
  // Define the active sheet
  var activeSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Shows");

  // Define the source spreadsheet using the provided ID
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetID");
  // Define the source sheet
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Shows");
  
  // Check if the edited sheet is the sourceSheet and column N is set to "confirmed"
  if (
    e.range.getSheet().getName() === sourceSheet.getName() &&
    e.range.getColumn() === 14 && // Column N
    e.value.toLowerCase() === "confirmed"
  ) {
    // Check if the first 4 digits of column K are not "Sold"
    var firstFourDigits = e.range.offset(0, -3).getValue().toString().slice(0, 4);
    if (firstFourDigits !== "Sold") {
      // Loop through each row in activeSheet
      var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
      for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++) {
        // Get value of column I ("idLookup") from activeSheet
        var idLookup = activeSheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
        
        // If idLookup is not empty, perform the update
        if (idLookup !== "") {
          // Create an index for all values in columns I-U per "idLookup"
          var indexedData = [];
          for (var j = 9; j <= 21; j++) {
            indexedData.push(activeSheet.getRange(i, j).getValue());
          }
          
          // Log indexed data in cloud log
          Logger.log("Index for idLookup '" + idLookup + "': " + indexedData.join(", "));
          
          // Look up value "idLookup" in activeSheet column A ("showID")
          var showID = activeSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
          
          // Paste indexed data to activeSheet columns I-U where "idLookup" matches "showID"
          activeSheet.getRange(i, 9, 1, indexedData.length).setValues([indexedData]);
          
          // For rows where "idLookup" is empty (""), copy "showID" to column I
          if (idLookup === "") {
            activeSheet.getRange(i, 9).setValue(showID);
          }
        }
      }
      
      // Show textbox "Shows have been updated"
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.alert("Shows have been updated");
    }
  }
}
```

I feel like I'm close to solving the problem, but for some reason, the edit to the source sheet is not being detected by the script. I'm not an expert & if this involves setting up an API, I would appreciate a detailed guide on how to do that.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be okay to provide the error message on the executions tab of the script to see what error you are getting when the onEdit function is triggered? Also would you be able to provide a sample sheet? 

You may use this [anonymous sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Comment: I do apologize if the answer did not help. I will delete the answer since this does not fully solve your question. Again, once a test sheet has been provided perhaps it would further help me and other community members provide an answer.

Comment: `onEdit will not be triggered by refreshing Imported data.